# An integral for $2\pi+e-9$

Tags: definite-integrals, exponential-function, pi, diophantine-approximation

**Motivation**

Lucian asked about the almost-integer $2\pi+e\approx9$ in a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1605706/why-is-e-close-to-h-8-closer-to-h-8-left1-frac1802-right-and-even#comment3272673_1605706) to a partially answered [*why* question about $e\approx H_8$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1605706/why-is-e-close-to-h-8-closer-to-h-8-left1-frac1802-right-and-even). This is more involved than [approximations to $\pi$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1654104/series-and-integrals-for-inequalities-and-approximations-to-pi) and [logarithms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1656344/series-and-integrals-for-inequalities-and-approximations-to-logn) because two transcendental constants are included, as in [$e^\pi-\pi\approx20$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1598664/why-e-pi-pi-approx-20-and-e2-pi-24-approx-29).

**Tried so far**

An answer can be crafted from integrals related to $\pi\approx\frac{22}{7}$ and $e\approx\frac{19}{7}$

$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}dx =\frac{22}{7}-\pi$$

$$\frac{1}{14}\int_0^1 x^2(1-x)^2e^xdx=e-\frac{19}{7}$$

to obtain

> $$\int_0^1 x^2 (1-x)^2 \left(\frac{e^x}{14}-\frac{2 x^2 (1-x)^2}{1+x^2}\right) dx = 2\pi+e-9 $$

The [visual representation of this integral](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1+x%5E2(1-x)%5E2%5Be%5Ex%2F14-2x%5E2(1-x)%5E2%2F(1%2Bx%5E2)%5Ddx) provided by WolframAlpha shows that $2\pi+e-9$ is positive and small (the integrand is between $0$ and $0.004$ for $0<x<1$), although this is not immediate from the analytic expression.

Moreover, two maxima appear, instead of the single one that is usual in this type of integrals.

**Question**

> **Is there a simpler integral with positive integrand in (0,1) that proves $2\pi+e\approx 9$?**

Comment: $$\int_0^1 x^4 \left(1 - x\right)^4 \left(\frac{2}{1 + x^2} -\frac{e^x}{24024} \right) dx = 9+\frac{4}{1001} - e - 2\pi$$
has one single maximum but the constant is not exactly 9.
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1+x%5E4(1-x)%5E4(-e%5Ex%2F24024%2B2%2F(1%2Bx%5E2))+dx

Comment: This can be used to write a double inequality

$9<2\pi+e<9+\frac{4}{1001}$

and suggests a question for a closer upper bound.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Approximations $e\approx \frac{163}{60} $ and $ \pi \approx \frac{377}{120}$ are related to the integrals

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 (1-x)^2\left(e^x-1-x-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)dx = e-\frac{163}{60}$$

and

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{x^5(1-x)^6}{1+x^2}dx = \frac{377}{120}-\pi.$$

Combining both, we can build
$$\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 (1 - x)^2 \left(e^x - 1 - x - \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{2 x^5 (1 - x)^4}{1 + x^2}\right) dx = 2\pi+e-9,$$

which explains the result with nonnegative small integrand and a single maximum in $(0,1)$.

[WolframAlpha link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1+(1-x)%5E2%5Be%5Ex-1-x-x%5E2%2F2-2x%5E5(1-x)%5E4%2F(1%2Bx%5E2)%5D%2F2+dx)

This sets the lower bound

$$9<2\pi+e$$

For an upper bound, we may take the integral from a failed attempt to match $9$

$$\int_0^1 x^4(1-x)^4\left(-\frac{e^x}{24024}+\frac{2}{1+x^2}\right) dx = 9+\frac{4}{1001}-2\pi-e$$
and write

$$2\pi+e<9+\frac{4}{1001}$$

Finally,

$$9<2\pi+e<9+\frac{4}{1001}$$

In short, $2\pi+e$ is close to $9$ because
$\pi\approx\dfrac{377}{120}$
from above,
$e \approx \dfrac{163}{60}$
from below and 
$$2·\frac{377}{120}+\frac{163}{60}=9$$