# Prove that: $e-\ln(10)>\sqrt 2-1.$

Tags: inequality, logarithms, approximation, exponentiation, number-comparison

The author's original inequality is as follows.

> Prove that:
> $$e-\ln(10)>\sqrt 2-1$$

Is there a good approximation for $$e-\ln 10?$$

Actually, I am also wondering that,
Where does $\sqrt 2-1$ come from?  Maybe, there exist relevant inequality?

My attempt:

$$-\ln 10>\sqrt 2-1-e\\
\ln 10<e+1-\sqrt 2\\
e^{e+1-\sqrt 2}>10$$

So, can we show that

$$e^x>10$$

when $x\ge e+1-\sqrt 2$?

I don't have a good idea.

Comment: Presumably whomever set the problem just noticed that the two sides are very close, and therefore thought it a clever problem.  Indeed, they only differ by $0.001483173$

Comment: In case it helps, the lowest-denominator fraction that's in between the two values is 17/41.

Comment: For there to be a "clever" method, I imagine that the inequality would have to have some mathematical significance (however hard that concept might be to define). Did the author express an opinion on that point?

Comment: @CalumGilhooley Integral representations can help.

Comment: @User Good point. Thinking caps on again, then $\ldots$

Comment: If this integral had nonnegative integrand, it would prove the result
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int_0%5E1+%28%28e%5Ex%29%281%2B%283x%29%5E2%29-18x%2B%281%2B9x%5E2%29%29%2F%281%2B9x%5E2%29-1%2F2%2Fsqrt%281%2Bx%29

Comment: It is similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1711437/an-integral-for-2-pie-9

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a proof that contains no numbers with more than five decimal digits.
\begin{gather*}
10 = \frac{65536}{6561}\times\frac{65610}{65536} =
\left(\frac43\right)^8\!\!\times\frac{65573 + 37}{65573 - 37} \\
\therefore\ \ln10 = 8\ln\left(\frac{1 + 1/7}{1 - 1/7}\right) +
\ln\left(\frac{1 + 37/65573}{1 - 37/65573}\right) \\
< 16\left(\frac17 + \frac{(1/7)^3}{3(1 - (1/7)^2)}\right) +
2\left(y + \frac{y^3}{3(1 - y^2)}\right),
\end{gather*}
where $y = 37/65573.$

We have
$$
16\left(\frac17 + \frac{(1/7)^3}{3(1 - (1/7)^2)}\right) =
\frac{16}7 + \frac1{3\cdot3\cdot7} = \frac{145}{63},
$$
and $y < 1/1000,$ therefore $1 - y^2 > 2/3,$ therefore
$$
2\left(y + \frac{y^3}{3(1 - y^2)}\right) < 2y + y^3 < 2y + 10^{-9}.
$$
Therefore:
$$
\ln10 < \frac{145}{63} + 2y + 10^{-9}.
$$

On the other hand, from [e Continued Fraction - from Wolfram MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/eContinuedFraction.html), we have:
$$
e > \frac{106}{39},
$$
and from [Square root of 2 - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2#Rational_approximations), or by simple
calculation:
$$
2 < \frac{9801}{4900} = \left(\frac{100 - 1}{70}\right)^2,
\quad \therefore\ \sqrt2 < \frac{99}{70}.
$$
Putting all the inequalities together, we get:
\begin{align*}
e - \sqrt2 + 1 - \ln10 & > \frac{106}{3\cdot13} -
\frac{29}{7\cdot10} - \frac{145}{7\cdot9} - 2y -  10^{-9} \\
& = \frac{106\cdot210 - 29\cdot117 - 145\cdot130}
{7\cdot9\cdot10\cdot13} - 2y -  10^{-9} \\
& = \frac{17}{8190} - \frac{74}{65573} - 10^{-9} \\
& > \frac{16}{8192} - \frac{74}{65536} - 10^{-9} \\
& = \frac{16}{8192} - \frac{128}{65536} + \frac{54}{65536} - 10^{-9}
\\ & = \frac1{512} - \frac1{512} + \frac{27}{32768} - 10^{-9} \\
& > 0.
\end{align*}

Comment: From a brute force search in Mathematica, the bounds $e > \frac{106}{39}$, $\ln 10 < \frac{76}{33}$, $\sqrt2 < \frac{58}{41}$ are the smallest ones (by total denominator) that prove the inequality. But proving these might be trickier than proving the bounds in this answer.

Comment: a fraction bound is no better than a decimal bound.

Comment: @ahala The question is recreational, in my opinion. As you point out in your answer, the proposition is merely a "numeric coincidence". It has zero mathematical or practical significance that I can see. But it's fun to try to prove such things without resorting to the use of machinery such as pocket calculators. Admittedly, (a) a pocket calculator or other device is well-nigh essential when working out whether a proposed hand calculation is feasible (e.g. working out $(4/3)^8,$ in the above example), and (b) there is little or no *practical* value in such proofs, if that's what matters to you.

Comment: Just to be clear: it's easy to calculate $(4/3)^8$ exactly by hand! But it's not so easy to arrive, in the first place, at the fact that $(4/3)^8$ is slightly less than $10,$ and is therefore convenient for calculating the logarithm, when there are many possibilities to look at. That's when I made essential use of a calculator.

Answer (score 4):

By Taylor's series at $196$:
$$\sqrt{2}=\frac{1}{10}\sqrt{200}<\frac{1}{10}(14+\frac{1}{7}-\frac{2}{14^3}+10^{-5})<1.4143\tag{1}$$
By Maclaurin's series:
$$e>1+1+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{24}+\frac{1}{120}+\frac{1}{720}>2,718\tag{2}$$
By using $\ln 10=-\ln(0.9)+2\ln3$:
$$-\ln(0.9)<\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{2\times10^2}+\frac{1}{3\times10^3}+10^{-4}<0.10544\tag{3}$$
and by using the Maclaurin series $\ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x})=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$, we have
$$2\ln 3<4(1+\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{80}+\frac{1}{448}+\frac{1}{2304}+10^{-4})<2.1972\tag{4}$$
Hence by $(3)$ and $(4)$,
$$\ln 10<0.10544+2.1972=2.30264\tag{5}$$
Finally by $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(5)$,
$$e+1-\sqrt{2}-\ln 10>2.718+1-1.4143-2.30264=0.00106>0.$$

Answer (score 3):

I think this is numeric coincidence.

Anyway, let $a = e - 1 + \sqrt{2}$, expand $e^x$ to eighth terms:
$$ e^a > \sum_{n=0}^{8}\frac{a^n}{n!} > 10.$$ One still needs a calculator but logically this seems right.

Comment: Is not it simpler to compute with a calculator $e-\ln10-\sqrt2+1$?

Comment: @user That's essentially what this answer is suggesting. And provided the method of computation generates a bound, it is a perfectly acceptable proof. Indeed, this method does provide such a bound, but others, such as iterative methods or the methods used by some calculators, may not.

Comment: @Jam This method uses a calculator as well.

Comment: @user Yes? I addressed that in my comment.

Comment: @Jam Then probably I wrongly understood your comment.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand. How do you get $a=e-1+\sqrt 2$?

Comment: @User/@user, it is at the same level of triviality to calculate $ln(10)$, $a$, and $e^a$. all need some Taylor expansion or numerical iteration. All need to say about the bounds of the error terms, therefore I dont think directly calculating $e-\ln10-\sqrt{2}+1$ by a calculator is easier.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly,
$$e >\dfrac1{0!}+\dfrac1{1!}+\dfrac1{2}+\dfrac1{6}+\dfrac1{24}+\dfrac1{120}+\dfrac1{720}+\dfrac1{5040}+\dfrac1{40320} = \dfrac{109601}{40320}>2.718278,$$
$$e>2.(7182) = 2+\dfrac{7182}{9999}=2+\dfrac{798}{1111}=\dfrac{3020}{1111}.\tag1$$
Then
$$12\cdot 3020^3 = 330523296000 > 330490682071 = 241\cdot 1111^3,$$
$$e^3>\dfrac{241}{12}=20\left(1+\dfrac1{240}\right).\tag2$$
From $\;(1)-(2)\;$ should
$$e^{76} > 20^{25}\cdot\left(1+\dfrac1{240}\right)^{25}\cdot \dfrac{3020}{1111}> \left(33554432\cdot 10^{25}\right)\cdot \left(1+\dfrac5{48}\right)\cdot \dfrac{3020}{1111}$$
$$> \dfrac{3\cdot 53\cdot 3020}{48}\cdot10^{29}>10^{33},$$
$$\ln 10<\dfrac{76}{33}.\tag3$$
At last,
$$(e+1-\ln10)^2 > \left(\dfrac{3020}{1111}+1-\dfrac{76}{33}\right)^2 
= \dfrac{4717^2}{3333^2} = \dfrac{22250089}{11108889}>2,$$
$$\color{green}{\mathbf{e-\ln10>\sqrt2-1}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

First we show that $\log 10 < 76/33$, since
$$
\exp\Big(\frac{76}{33}\Big) > \sum_{n=0}^9 \frac{76^n}{33^n\,n!} = \frac{1316160031686037871}{131576558279536755}>10\,.
$$
Now it is readily seen that
$$
\frac{76}{33}<\frac{67997}{29520}\,,=1+1+\frac 1 2+\frac 1 6 + \frac 1{24}+\frac 1{120}+\frac 1{720}-\frac{17}{41}\,,
$$
hence
$$
\log 10<\frac{76}{33} < e - \frac{17}{41} = e+1-\frac{58}{41}\,,
$$
and finally (since $58/41 >\sqrt 2$)
$$
e-\log 10 > \sqrt 2 - 1\,.
$$

Answer (score 1):

I hope the following will help.
$$\ln10=\ln2+\ln5=2\left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^3}{3}+\frac{\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^5}{5}+\frac{\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^7}{7}+...\right)+$$
$$+2\left(\frac{2}{3}+\frac{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3}{3}+\frac{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^5}{5}+\frac{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^7}{7}+...\right)<$$$$<2\left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^3}{3}+\frac{\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^5}{5}+\frac{\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^7}{7}+\frac{\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^9}{7}+\frac{\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{11}}{7}+...\right)+$$
$$+2\left(\frac{2}{3}+\frac{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3}{3}+\frac{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^5}{5}+\frac{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^7}{7}+\frac{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^9}{9}+\frac{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{11}}{11}+\frac{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{13}}{13}+\frac{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{15}}{13}+...\right)=$$$$=2\left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^3}{3}+\frac{\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^5}{5}+\frac{\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^7}{7}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^2}\right)+$$
$$+2\left(\frac{2}{3}+\frac{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3}{3}+\frac{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^5}{5}+\frac{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^7}{7}+\frac{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^9}{9}+\frac{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{11}}{11}+\frac{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{13}}{13}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{8166549323}{3546482940}.$$

Can you end it now?

Comment: You obviously assume the values of $e$ and $\sqrt2$ to be known.

Comment: @user Approximations for $e$ and for $\sqrt2$  I am ready to show for you by hand. Do you want?

Comment: I am not the @User who asked the question. Let him decide whether he wants. :)

Comment: @user Please don't assume anonymous people are male; that exacerbates the problem of women and gender-binary people feeling unwelcome in mathematics settings.